# Radio Button not performing JavaScript action when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, radio-button, boolean

I am trying to create a radio button that opens up an additional checkbox. When I run the code, the checkbox is already open. what can I do to fix it?

```html
<script>
  function accountFunction() {
    if (document.getElementById('yesSrm').checked) {
      document.getElementById('acct').style.display = "inline";
    } else {
      document.getElementById('acct').style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
<form>
  <input id="yesSrm" name="yesSrm" type="radio" value="yes" onchange="accountFunction()" />SRM<br/>
  <br/>
  <div id="acct">
    <label for="account">Account</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="account" id="account"><br/>
  </div>
</form>
```

[How it appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRr89.png)

Comment: Your current syntax is incorrect.

Comment: Not sure exactly where I made the mistake

Comment: Press "Run code snippet". `accountFunction` does not have a `}`.

Comment: Oh geez. I never closed it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just add `display:none` to `acct` block to hide it by default

```html
<script>
  function accountFunction() {
    if (document.getElementById('yesSrm').checked) {
      document.getElementById('acct').style.display = "block";
    } else {
      document.getElementById('acct').style.display = "none";
    }
  }
</script>
<form>
  <input id="yesSrm" name="yesSrm" type="radio" value="yes" onchange="accountFunction()" />SRM<br/>
  <br/>
  <div id="acct" style="display: none">
    <label for="account">Account</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="account" id="account"><br/>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I really appreciate it!